# I want to play gif every time I click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

### Current status

I have a gif that is played only once.
I want to play gif every time I click the button.
For now, once it finish playing gif, it stop moving at the end after the second time.

---

### Current code

CSS

```
    html { font-size: 62.5%; }

.target {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 37.6rem;
  height: 31.1rem;
  background: url(https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190410/20190410164103.gif);
}

@mixin ghost {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-color: #fff;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in, border-color 0.3s ease-in;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

@keyframes inhale {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    top: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: calc(100% - 100px);
    transform: scale(0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

iframe {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.clsbtn {
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  z-index: 111;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  &:hover {
    @include ghost;
  }
}

.inhale {
  animation: inhale 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, .56, 1);
}
```

jQuery

```
var timeStamp  = new Date().getTime();
        $(".target").attr('background','url(../img/score.gif' + '?' + timeStamp + ')');
```

The whole picture

```
function closeBtn() {
    $(".clsbtn").on('click', function() {
        var target = $("<div>").addClass('target');

        // here
        var timeStamp  = new Date().getTime();
        $(".target").attr('background','url(../img/score.gif' + '?' + timeStamp + ')');

        $(this).hide();
        $("iframe").addClass('inhale').before(target).one('animationend', function() {
            $("iframe").removeClass('inhale').empty(target);
            $("#items").magnificPopup('close');
        });
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="items">
    <section class="item" data-mfp-src="data1.html">
      <img src="img/a.png" alt="a" />
      <h2>title1</h2>
      <p>description1</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item" data-mfp-src="data2.html">
      <img src="img/b.png" alt="b" />
      <h2>title2</h2>
      <p>description2</p>
    </section>
...
</div>
```

In my case, how can I play gif per click?

---

### Add

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/dycohvf5/11/)
[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbyOVX)

When I tried it with JSFiddle and codepen, it worked correctly. :O
(A gif is played with every click)

Does gif not work properly in a local environment?

Comment: add your html please

Comment: `var timeStamp  = new Date().getTime();` is probably stale second time around. try to change `new Date()` to `Date.now()`

Comment: @לבני מלכה I don't use HTML, so there is no..

Comment: @zer00ne Thank you.
I changed it to `Date.now ()`, but the close button didn't work, so it didn't work.. :(

Comment: You don't use HTML but use jQuery to target HTML elements/classes/IDs?

Comment: @Jeto I feel that it's not related to the question, but I added all the HTML used here.
The rest of  `.clsbtn` , `inhale` , etc. are all written only in CSS, and are added in JS.

Comment: @POP see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606780/2813224)

Comment: @POP The part that was emphasized: `var timeStamp  = new Date().getTime();
        $(".target").attr('background','url(../img/score.gif' + '?' + timeStamp + ')');` is the only part of the code that can be removed without killing the code. It looks as if it is the only part that was added to the original code. It's completely useless. The only crucial part was the omitted CSS.  I'm sure if you had copied it correctly with or without that timestamp/attr() fiasco it would work. https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/dycohvf5/11/ was working all this time

Comment: @zer00ne thank you for your comment.
In other words, what kind of thing are you saying?
(I'm sorry, I could not understand well because of the limitations of google translation and my lack of English skills. I'm sorry if I say something strange in ↓'s comment!)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(".target").attr('background', ...)` set `$(".target").css('background', ...)`, elements don't have native `background` attribute, and setting it doesn't trigger any native action.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Changed to `.css()` but it didn't work..
I also tried the other person's `.one()` → `.on()` advice, but after the second click, the gif remains still.. x(

Comment: @POP Is the `closeBtn` function ever executed?

Comment: Yes, every time the button closes as expected, but only gif will stop after the second time.

However, when I tried it with JSFiddle and Codepen, gif was executed correctly. (?!)
Does gif not work properly locally?

Comment: @POP the fiddle/codepen work because the CSS/JQuery was complete. You can't seriously post half-baked code for the question then post working code afterwards it's a waste of time. BTW about that `.attr()`/`.css()` part Teemu is correct in that `.attr()` is totally wrong, moreover `.css()` is correct but in the context of the OP code it is completely useless either way. I removed it from the working code and it still functions. Of course how is anyone to know with the scant code that was initially provided by OP?

Comment: @zer00ne I'm sorry.. I see. My local environment is chrome, but when I tried to read it with safari, gif was played with every click.
So, I think maybe it's a bug in chrome..